# I am unable to create a file that does not exist and write to it using w+ mode

Tags: python, windows, web-scraping, scrapy, operating-system

I am trying to create a folder and write files to it even though the folder orignally doesn't exists but I am getting **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**.

I believe using the **w+** mode oughts to create the file whether it exists or not and then write to it but it doesn't seem to be working and i keep getting the **FileNotFoundError**. I also tried using the a+ or r+ but none seem to be working.

error log:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\fighter\\fighters-n.json'
```

ufcscraper.py:

```
page = response.url.split("&")[0][-1]
# a sample of the page url structure is: http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all
filename = f'fighters-{page}.json'

path = os.getcwd() # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\ufccrawler\\spiders'
new_path = path.split("\\")[0:-2] # ['C:', 'Users', 'Habib', 'Documents', 'Upwork_Projects', 'Stephanie-web-scraping', 'ufccrawler']
new_path = ("\\").join(new_path) + "\\fighter" # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\fighter'
completeName = os.path.join(new_path, filename) # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\fighter\\fighters-a.json'

with open(completeName, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
    f.close()
self.log(f'Saved file {completeName}')
```

Comment: What about `fighter`? Does it exist?

Comment: it doesn't exist, that is why i used the w+ mode so that python could create that itself and write the files to it.

Comment: Wait. `filter` is a directory. `w+` opens a file for read and write. If does not exist it will create _the file_. But it cannot create a directory if it does not exist in the path.

Comment: ohh. so it only opens new file not folder, so how can I create a new folder that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think i figured that out, using the "os.makedirs()" works out well.

Comment: That's the way. But I would advise you to make a more robust method to first check if a path exist. If it does not then create the directory. Otherwise you will get error upon creating a directory which is already exist.

Comment: exactly what I did, check it out in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
page = response.url.split("&")[0][-1]
# a sample of the page url structure is: http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all
filename = f'fighters-{page}.json'

path = os.getcwd() # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\ufccrawler\\spiders'
new_path = path.split("\\")[0:-2] # ['C:', 'Users', 'Habib', 'Documents', 'Upwork_Projects', 'Stephanie-web-scraping', 'ufccrawler']
new_path = ("\\").join(new_path) + "\\fighter" # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\fighter'

# This fixes the issue for me by checking to see if the directory exist or not and the creates it if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(new_path):
    os.makedirs(new_path)

completeName = os.path.join(new_path, filename) # 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\Upwork_Projects\\Stephanie-web-scraping\\ufccrawler\\fighter\\fighters-a.json'

with open(completeName, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
    f.close()
self.log(f'Saved file {completeName}')
```